# Embed Unity game within ReactNative (handling bidirectional communication)

Tags: unity-game-engine, react-native, bidirectional

I am creating a multi-mobile (iOS/Android) app with React Native.

The app needs to embed & launch a Unity game.

It will need to send information to the game, and also receive information *from* the game. A function passing a JSON string would be sufficient.

Six years ago I embedded native iOS code within a Unity app and it was rather a dark art.

What is the state of play in 2018?

Presumably it is going to involve separate iOS and Android codebases and a ReactNative component to wrap these, providing a single JavaScript interface.  At the Unity end, I'm not sure if it will require separate per-platform coding.

Comment: Nowadays embedding native code is quite easy. You can add java and object c classes and import their functionality to use them in your Unity project. For react native, besides some tryouts there are no real libraries for achieving this yet.